# How to pass an instance variable into a view partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have a loop that contains code I do not wish to repeat for each instance variable. I wish to put this in a partial and reuse it by changing the **@new_posts** instance variable, so I can use the same template for  @featured_posts and @recommended_posts that I have defined.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
<%= render "posts", posts: @featured_posts %>
```

An example of a loop that I wish to store in a partial

```
<% @new_posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <div class="thumbnail">
 <img src="#">
 <div class="caption">
   <h4><%= link_to post.title, post %></h4>
   <%= post.text.truncate_words(60, omission: '...') %>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button">Button</a>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

How should I approach this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign whatever variable you want to `posts`

```
<%= render "posts", posts: @featured_posts %>
```

And now loop over `posts` in the partial. You will have `@featured_posts` in `posts` variable now

```
<% posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="#">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4><%= link_to post.title, post %></h4>
        <%= post.text.truncate_words(60, omission: '...') %>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

For `@recommended_posts` render the same partial but pass `@recommended_posts` to `posts`

```
<%= render "posts", posts: @recommended_posts %>
```